# Are Banksy's 2018 Paris murals still visible in Paris and if so, where?

Tags: paris, artworks

In 2018 Banksy put up some graffiti in Paris, per https://www.bbc.com/news/world-europe-44648562.

I'm curious...  how much of that graffiti is still there? And what are the locations of said graffiti if it is still there?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[The Local](https://www.thelocal.fr/20180628/map-where-to-find-the-new-banksy-artworks-in-paris/) published a list (feel free to edit to update the status).

- Porte de la Chapelle (18th): Defaced quickly after it was painted in 2018.
- Rue Victor Cousin (5th): Apparently [painted over](https://creationpreservationdeteriorationofstreetart.wordpress.com/)
- Avenue de Flandre (19th): Unknown
- Rue Maitre Albert (5th): Was still there later in 2018, not sure of 2022 status.
- Rue Rambuteau (3rd): Found it in 2018, didn't see it when I was in the neighbourhood last week (July 2022) but I am not 100% sure where it was anymore.
- Rue du Mont Cenis (18th): Unknown
- Chez Marianne, 2 Rue des Hospitalières Saint-Gervais (4th): Partially defaced in 2018 but possibly still there?
- Bataclan, 50 Boulevard Voltaire (11th): It [was apparently stolen then reclaimed](https://www.thelocal.fr/20200801/how-police-reclaimed-a-stolen-bataclan-banksy-in-italy/), current status unknown.
- Pont Rouelle – RER viaduct (16th): Long gone, there was already nothing to see by the summer 2018.